# How to make recommendation with KNN

Tags: python, python-3.x, knn, recommendation-engine, cosine-similarity

I am building a simple book recommender where I only have certain book information (price, title, author, genre, publishing date) and **no user information** at all (no ratings, no demographics) just their **purchase history**.

So I want to make recommendations based only this purchase history, as an example: user A bought book1, book2 and book3, and user B bought book1, book3 and book4, if I want to get recommendations for user A I can assume book4 would be a good one given that they share similar interests based on their purchase history.

I'm trying to implement KNN with cosine similarity but I don't really know how to give recommendations based on the user, I mean, I've built the matrix and I've chosen the parameters but I don't know how to use the results to give a list of recommended books given an user.

Here's how my matrix looks (simplified):

```
product    63767    76863    84325    86217    86833    130365   537077   830166   997165   1023897
username                                                                                           
45michael      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      1.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
7762hc         0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
adrian12       0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
alicia7        0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
angel8         0.0      0.0      0.0      1.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
```

Where 1 represents if the user bought the book and 0 if he/she didn't.

And here is what I've done so far:

```
# Matrix with users as rows, products as columns and count as content
df_matrix = pd.pivot_table(order_df, values='count', index='username', columns='product')
# Replace all NaN contents with 0
df_matrix_dummy = df_matrix.fillna(0)

# Convert dataframe of books features to scipy sparse matrix
product_matrix = csr_matrix(df_matrix_dummy.values)

model_knn = NearestNeighbors(metric='cosine', algorithm='brute', n_neighbors=20, n_jobs=-1)
```

Can someone give me a hand or point me into a good tutorial?

Comment: I assume your  are using `sklearn` ,have you done operations like  `model_knn.fit(product_matrix)` and then prediction by using `model_knn.kneighbors()`,also check out this sklean [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors.html)

Comment: I've done that but I can't really understand the array `model_knn.kneighbors()` returns

Comment: My goal is to make something like [this](https://rpubs.com/ferranmt/80166) but in python, where the recommendation is made given a user and its book purchase history